# How to make spinning cube in directx?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm learning directx programming. Yesterday I succeeded in making a cube.
I'm trying to making a spinning cube. In fact, I succeeded but I'm not sure I use the correct way.

Is the code below commonly used way? I call function which translate vertex position and make new vertex buffer on every frames. Is there any other way which not create vertex buffer on every frames? Is there a more effective way to prove performance?

```
void BoxApp::makeVertex()
{
    Vertex vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::White },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Black },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Red },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Green },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Blue },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Cyan },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const XMFLOAT4)Colors::Magenta }
    };
    rotating_angle += 0.01;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        XMStoreFloat3(&vertices[i].pos, XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3(&vertices[i].pos),
            XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) *
            XMMatrixRotationX(rotating_angle) *
            XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f)
        ));
    }

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    ... #Set BUFFER_DESC
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    ... #Set SUBRESURCE
    md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mBoxVB);
}
```

Comment: You do the rotation inside a Vertex Shader against your static Vertex Buffer using a Constant Buffer where you update the current rotation. Don't update on each frame. Track time and update based on elapsed time. Just a spinning cube will have an obscene amount of FPS. *PS: I'm really noob in DX programming. Don't ask for code! :)*

Comment: You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and in particular the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)

Answer (score 0):

Set vertex position as local coordinate and make transformation matrix from local to world coordinate. send it to a vertex shader using a constant buffer.